# CSS background color not showing up on live server: what could be the issue?

Tags: css

I had a background color that was set for my `#background` div. Then added some `display: grid` to other sections and the background color has now disappeared. My css still has the `#background` element and color is chosen however it is not showing up on my live server when I update. Can anybody please help?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.google.com/");
div {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
  color: #00b4d8;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 35px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00b4d8
}

.home-title {
  background-color: #03045e;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

h4 {
  background-color: #03045e;
  color: white;
}

#hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr 1fr;
}

#hero-img {
  width: 100%;
}

#hero-box {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

#hero-msg h1,
#hero-msg h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

#hero-msg {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.logo {
  width: 80px;
}

#logo_link {
  padding-top: 5px;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.icon {
  width: 80px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.home-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr);
}

main section {
  text-align: center;
}

main section img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #03045e;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px auto;
}

.book,
.join {
  background-color: #0077b6;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.book:hover,
.join:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00b4d8;
}

.rivers-card,
.camping-card,
.rapids-card {
  margin: 200px 0;
}

.rivers-card {
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.camping-card {
  grid-column: 5/7;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.rapids-card {
  grid-column: 8/10;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.mountains {
  width: 100%;
  grid-column: 2/7;
  grid-row: 5/8;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #00b4d8;
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid black;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #00b4d8;
}

.card-img:hover {
  opacity: .6;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#background {
  height: 725px;
  background-color: #0077b6;
  grid-column: 1/11;
  grid-row: 4/9;
}

.msg {
  background-color: #03045e;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding: 35px;
  grid-column: 6/10;
  grid-row: 6/7;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #00b4d8;
}

.msg h2 {
  color: #00b4d8;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
}

.msg p {
  color: #00b4d8;
  font-size: .8em;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #03045e;
  color: #00b4d8;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

footer .social img {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

footer p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 25px;
}

footer p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer a {
  color: #00b4d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #00b4d8;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #hero,
  .home-grid {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }
  nav,
  footer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  #hero {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #hero-msg {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  #hero-msg h4 {
    display: none;
  }
  .home-title {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #6f7364;
  }
  .rivers-card,
  .camping-card,
  .rapids-card {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 60%;
  }
  #background {
    display: none;
  }
  .mountains,
  .msg {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  footer {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&family=Merriweather:wght@300&family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Whitewater Rafting Gathering | Dry Oar Boating | Home </title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <header>
      <a id="logo_link" href="index.html">
        <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Dry Oar Logo">
      </a>
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <a href="site-plan-rafting.html">Site Plan</a>
        <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="hero">
      <div id="hero-box">
        <img id="hero-img" src="images/hero.png" alt="People enjoying white water rafting">
      </div>
      <section id="hero-msg">
        <h1 class="home-title">Have An Adventure</h1>
        <h4>Make Memories with Dry Oar </h4>
        <div class='button-box'>
          <a class='book' href="contactus.html">Book Now</a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <main class="home-grid">
      <section class="rivers-card">
        <img class="card-img" src="images/rivers.jpeg" alt="river in forest">
        <img class="icon" src="images/river_icon.png" alt="river icon">
        <h2>Rivers</h2>
      </section>
      <section class="camping-card">
        <img class="card-img" src="images/camping.jpeg" alt="tent in mountains">
        <img class="icon" src="images/fire_icon.png" alt="fire icon">
        <h2>Camping</h2>
      </section>
      <section class="rapids-card">
        <img class="card-img" src="images/rapids.jpeg" alt="rafting boat">
        <img class="icon" src="images/oars.png" alt="oars icon">
        <h2>Rapids</h2>
      </section>
      <div id="background"></div>
      <img class="mountains" src="images/mountains.jpeg" alt="Misty mountains">
      <section class="msg">
        <h2>More Than Just The Thrill</h2>
        <p>Enjoy the breathtaking scenery. From valleys, meadows, canyons, and high peaks; it's way more than just the rapids. It's a great way to get away from it all and relax amongst all the beauty of the great outdoors. </p>
        <a class='join' href="rivers.html">Join Us</a>
      </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Dry Oar &copy; 2023 - Isileli Fiefia</p>
      <p><a href="site-plan-rafting.html">Site Plan</a></p>
      <p><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
      <div class="social">
        <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="fb icon">
        </a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter icon">
        </a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
          <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram icon">
        </a>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your CSS you have `#background{display:none}`, but even if you remove this the background color won't be visible again as this div is empty and by default it has `height:0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a width to your element, so that it takes up space on the website.

Try this:

```
#background {
   height: 725px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #0077b6;
   grid-column: 1/11;
   grid-row: 4/9;
}
```

Also remember that you are you are removing the background with the

```
#background {
   display: none;
}
```

In the `@media screen and (max-width: 900px)`